# In Google Maps - drawn polylines do not scale correctly with map zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to draw a polygon to mark a service area in a city. I want to make it as accurate as possible but one issue I'm getting is that the polylines I place they do not scale well with the roads when I zoom in/out.

Is this just the way Google Maps work or is there a way to make polylines scale correctly with the roads so that it aligns perfectly at any zoom level?

Made a quick gif to showcase the effect: https://i.gyazo.com/57add48fbb8ffa0d0253e5cd6e2d36c3.mp4

I'm using this polygon tool on my website: https://github.com/jeremy-hawes/google-maps-coordinates-polygon-tool

Comment: It seems same problem in the github  codepen demo

Comment: I would expect you would need a unique polygon for each zoom level of you want it to be "perfect".  Google's tiles could be different for each zoom level. So I guess as you said "this is just the way Google Maps works".

Comment: It's the same effect on all polygon drawing tools, so I guess not much I can do here.

Comment: I think the polygon is where it should be. The issue is more with the way google displays the roads. Their aspect seems to change a little bit depending on the zoom level, which is not the case with other elements like buildings, for example.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on what I could do in this situation? I guess I'm a neat-freak so it just bugs me when it doesn't align properly.